# How to replace a value in dataframe based on a value from another column in same dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe obtained after reading a table as below using spark:

```
val orgDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options("url", url).options("dbtable","select id, org_name, delete_state, soft_del, 0 as soft_del from schema.table as orgTable").options("user",username)options("password",pwd).load()
```

I can see the output data from the dataframe as below:

```
-----------------------------------------
id | org_name  | delete_state | soft_del
-----------------------------------------
1  | Net       | delete       |   0
2  | Vert      | delete       |   0
3  | Bio       | insert       |   0
4  | Card      | delete       |   0
7  | stock     | update       |   0
-----------------------------------------
```

Before saving the dataframe on HDFS, I am trying to set the value of the col: soft_del as '1' if the vale of the column in `delete_state` is `delete`
and make a final dataframe as below:

```
  -----------------------------------------
    id | org_name  | delete_state | soft_del
    -----------------------------------------
    1  | Net       | delete       |   1
    2  | Vert      | delete       |   1
    3  | Bio       | insert       |   0
    4  | Card      | delete       |   1
    7  | Stock     | update       |   0
    -----------------------------------------
```

I know there is a way to do it as below:

```
orgDF.createOrReplaceTempView("orgData")
spark.sql("update orgData set soft_del = 1 where delete_state = 'delete'")
```

I am also trying to get to know how to use dataframe functions and do it but unable to find correct material.
Could anyone let know how can I do it using dataframe functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
orgDF.withColumn("soft_del", when($"delete_state" === "delete", 1).otherwise(0))
```

You can also chain multiple `when`s if you need, something like

```
orgDF.withColumn("soft_del", 
  when($"delete_state" === "delete", 1)
  .when($"delete_state" === "update", 2)
  .otherwise(0)
)
```

Reference

- [scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@when(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) of `when` function.

Comment: orgDF already has the column: "soft_del", doesn't withColumn create a conflict by trying to create a new column with same ? or would it use the existing one in such cases ?

Comment: It would drop the existing column and create a new version of `soft_del` column with the new set of values. If you want to keep the old column as well you can use a combination of `withColumnRenamed` to rename the existing column to a new name and use `withColumn` to create a new column with the old name.